# Finbuckle does not support multiple multitenant resolution using EntityFramework Core

Tags: multi-tenant, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I am working on a project using .NET 7 and  EntityFramework Core 7 and leveraging the Finbuckle.MultiTenant package for multitenancy. However, I've encountered an issue where the Finbuckle.MultiTenant package doesn't seem to support multiple multitenant resolution in EntityFramework Core 7.

I've set up my application to use Finbuckle.MultiTenant for multitenancy, and it works well for single tenant resolution. However, when trying to support multiple tenants and resolving them based on specific criteria, it doesn't behave as expected.

Is there a known limitation in Finbuckle.MultiTenant when it comes to handling multiple multitenant resolution in EntityFramework Core 7?

[image]

header x-tenant1 is mapped with Tenant1 class

header x-tenant2 is mapped with Tenant2 class

header x-tenant3 is mapped with Tenant3 class

[image]

Here on trying to get tenant information for tenant1, tenant2 and tenant3, However we get tenant1 information only. For others tenant2 and tenant3 the values are null.

[image]

Are there any workarounds or alternative approaches I could use to achieve this functionality with EntityFramework Core 7 and Finbuckle.MultiTenant? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance